# What is the meaning of [type]* for arrays?

Tags: programming

I've seen * used with arrays in some programs but not in others. [The page on arrays](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/array) doesn't mention it at all, but I often see it near functions when values are being passed.

Where would I find more information on this?

Comment: There are several possible usages, each with its own meaning, so you are going to have to ask about a specific example.  One possibility is the fact that you can have an array *of* pointers, a pointer to an array, etc, but there is also the related fact that that arrays readily and gracefully degrade to pointers.

Comment: Ok! Looks like I was talking about pointers [Time to learn today](https://xkcd.com/1053/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about Pointers -
 https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm.